# Delegates for logging

Tags: c#, .net, logging, delegates, refactoring

How can I refactor this piece of code?

```
ulong get_item_action_id = log.LogAction(iteration_id, "GET_ITEM_SERVICE");
try
{
    p = serv.GetItemById(get_item_action_id, ls.externalItem.item);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    log.LogActionResult(get_item_action_id, false, exc);
    continue;
}
log.LogActionResult(get_item_action_id, true);
```

The scenario here is:

1. logging try of getting action and retrieving logged action id
   (`ulong get_item_action_id = log.LogAction(iteration_id,
   "GET_ITEM_SERVICE");`)
2. Properly, acting (`p = serv.GetItemById(get_item_action_id, ls.externalItem.item);`)
3. Logging success or fail result (`log.LogActionResult(get_item_action_id, false, exc);` or `log.LogActionResult(get_item_action_id, true);`)

So, I think I could rewrite it using some delegates, but how?

Comment: Where and why do you want to use delegates?

Comment: I want to recode try { } catch block, because I got a lot of such constructions.

Comment: What do you gain by refactoring as a delegate, over refactoring as a static/non-static method? I suggest you first refactor as a method, then refactor to a delegate.

Comment: @ZevSpitz The reason is that I got not just one serv.GetItemByid() method, but a lot of different methods.

Comment: I would refactor out the logging in the code, refactor the code into a method that succeeds or throws an exception, then use the Decorator Pattern to wrap the call to the method and do appropriate logging (log if success, or "error" if an exception occurred").  I don't see a benefit of using delegates over a `log` instance.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Could you please share a code sample on decorator?

Comment: @kseen you haven't really provided much of the code to give a really good example

Comment: If you get a lot of those constructions, show us another construction so we all can see what is duplicate and what is not.